# "Hacking" progress in Rosetta Stone after progress file was corrupted?

Tags: progress, rosetta-stone

I have a friend who is using Rosetta Stone to learn Korean. Recently she was faced with a 5118 error which resulted in all of her progress being lost. She was on the second to last section, which is a lot of work to get back to, and finishing is necessary for graduation (homeschooled).

Is there anyway to "hack" the progress levels that have been completed, or is there any way that one might be able to speed up the process of getting back to where they were?

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What OS? If you are using Windows 7 and you can find where the progress is stored you might be able to use the Previous Versions feature of Windows 7 to recover the progress. Sadly they removed this feature in Windows 8...

Comment: Have you looked at Rosetta Stone's support site for [Error 5118](http://support.rosettastone.com/en/language-learning/articles/I-receive-error-5118-in-Rosetta-Stone-Version-3/)?

Comment: @CharlieRB, yes, and she did a chat session with Rosetta.

Comment: @Mokubai, tried and failed, sadly.